# SQL Netezza - How to round datetime to nearest day

Tags: sql, netezza

I've been using CAST to round a datetime but now, I want to round the datetime to the nearest day.

For example,
If my datetime is '2012-10-27 21:11:19:207', I want to round to '2012-10-28'
But if my datetime is ''2012-10-27 09:11:19:207', I want to round to '2012-10-27'.

I've been googling and searching but couldn't find an answer.  Please help.

Comment: Care to explain why you want to round off dates? Usually one would want to take the date as is from timestamp.

Comment: `date_trunc('day', col)` -- At least, that is how Postgres does it.

Comment: In my situation, there's a record of data everytime there's a change to an applicant's profile.

So, if I want to specify exactly which record to look at for an applicant at a specific time, if I just take the datetime, I might be looking at two records.





I'm not sure if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to round the to the nearest day, rather than truncate to the current date, you could do some case logic like this:

```
select 
        current_timestamp, 
        case 
                when current_timestamp - date_trunc('day',current_timestamp) < '12 hours'::INTERVAL
                then date_trunc('day',current_timestamp)
                else date_trunc('day',current_timestamp) + '1 day' ::interval
        end ROUNDED_DATE;


TIMESTAMP           ROUNDED_DATE        
------------------- ------------------- 
2016-03-18 09:00:21 2016-03-18 00:00:00
```